# If a pipeline stage is stalled due to a dependency, do all the stages which follow get stalled for that cycle?

Tags: cpu-architecture, pipelining

If a pipeline stage in a MIPS architecture is stalled due to a dependency, do all the stages which follow get stalled for that cycle? If yes, why?
e.g.

```
                                                 1  2    3    4    5    6     7
    add r1, r2, (r3)                            IF  ID  MEM  EX    WB       
    sub r4, r5, (r1)                                IF  ID  stall  MEM  EX    WB  
    st  r4, 0(r10)                                      IF  stall  ID  stall  MEM
```

In this example, can we do ID of the third instruction in cycle 4? To be more precise, is this allowed -

```
                                                 1  2    3   4     5    6     7
    add r1, r2, (r3)                            IF  ID  MEM  EX    WB       
    sub r4, r5, (r1)                                IF  ID  stall  MEM  EX   WB     
    st  r4, 0(r10)                                      IF   ID  stall stall MEM
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know the (micro-)architecture you are asking about.

Comment: The architecture is MIPS. Edited the question.

Comment: MIPS (like most other CPU's from this millennium) comes in various configurations, superscalar, superpipelined, out-of-order. So which configuration are you looking for? from your question it could be the R2000?

Answer (score 3):

If you were to remove the stalls from the 3rd instruction, you'd have two instructions reaching the Mem stage simultaneously (or rather - both would try to write to the preceding latch together), which is impossible -

```
                                             1  2    3    4     5    6  7
add r1, r2, (r3)                            IF  ID  MEM  EX     WB       
sub r4, r5, (r1)                                IF  ID   stall  MEM  EX      
st  r4, 0(r10)                                      IF   ID     MEM   
                                                               ^^^^^
```

Now, you may claim that the second stall would have allowed us to avoid that collision, but note that the first stall was done at cycle 4, where you still have no knowledge of the second one. You can't just assume it will be all right.

Generally speaking, when dealing with a simple ordered pipeline, there's no sense in letting younger operations "run ahead" when older ones are stalled, you can't pass them and you can't improve the throughput, you're only going to cause such collisions.

This of course no longer applies when dealing with out-of-order CPUs, where a younger instruction may still be of use even when older ones are stalled (because the strict order dependency is replaced by actual data dependency), but there you have a huge logic to reorder all the operations that end up flying around all over the place.